# Trying to set a watch on a register in Visual Studio 2017's debugger: "Error reading register value"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, x86-64, visual-studio-debugging

I'm currently working through an [x64 Assembly Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNDNvm0UY8E)  on YouTube.

All I'm doing now is basic stuff like using `C++` functions in `ASSEMBLY` and moving values into registers using the `mov` instruction.

Here's the `C++` code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" void SomeFunction();

int main() {
    SomeFunction();

    // Just putting this here to stop the program from closing immediately after opening
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the `ASSEMBLY` code:

```
.code
SomeFunction proc               
    mov ax, -1          
    ret                                 
SomeFunction endp
end
```

**THE ISSUE:** I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017, whenever I run Local Window Debugger and try *adding a Watch* to the register `ax`, but I keep getting the error message `'Error reading register value'`.

Where am I going wrong?

Apologies if this is not clear, please let me know and I can try explain better.

---

**UPDATE:** So I tried using the `rbx` register instead and I was able to add a watch to it. But the issue now is, it's telling me it contains no value (Value section just shows 0), despite the fact I used `mov` to move the value `-1` in the register.

Don't know if this information helps.

Comment: Never thought of adding a Watch to a register, but there is Debug >> Windows >> Registers where you can watch *all* the registers.

Comment: @BoPersson Registers window seem to always show values in hex which is not very convenient while Watch window allows to select format.

Comment: Does this issue occur if you try to set `ax` watch on normal code without any assembly?

Comment: If your debugger allows a Watch on a register at all, maybe it only works for full registers (like RAX), not partial registers.  The normal thing for watching registers change is what Bo suggested, using the register-display window.  Set a breakpoint on a specific instruction or function and then single-step (by instructions, not source lines, if you're stepping through compiler-output asm).

Comment: @VTT - As in just on C++? (Sorry, I'm a beginner).

Comment: @PeterCordes - I thought so too, so I tried using the RAX register, but still got the same error message.

Comment: @BoPersson - I used the RAX register instead of AX and viewed all registers. The RAX was set to `00000000`

Comment: You know that `ax` is the low 16 bits of RAX, right?  i.e. the low 4 hex digits.  Anyway, sounds like you can't set watchpoints on registers.  Did you have any reason to expect that was supported?  Did the tutorial suggest you could do that?  Or does the Visual Studio debugger's UI imply that registers work?  (IDK, I don't use it.  But most debuggers don't usually support register watches.  There is hardware support for memory watchpoints without single-stepping which is useful because the same instruction can use a variable address, but the destination register of an instruction is fixed.)

Comment: Yes, I mean just normal C++ program. Maybe there is something wrong with your build process when you use an assembly parts. For me setting `ax` or any other register watch works fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I linked the tutorial, at about 7:44, he right clicks the registers and adds a watch. Thank you so much for the replies :)

Comment: As non-windows user (last time I used VS, it was v6.x, sometime around year 2000), isn't the new VS installation quite modular? Maybe you are missing some kind of disassembly support in debugger? Sounds absolutely ridiculous to me (to have support for machine level optional and not built-in), but if you have by chance any pre-requisites list "how to install the MS SDKs for asm development", re-check if you have all required modules installed. Unfortunately I have no better idea or suggestion, maybe some windows user will be able to help more.

Comment: @Ped7g - Thank you for commenting. I changed from `rax` to `rbx` register and it seems to allow me to add a watch to it. However, it tells me the register is empty (has value 0), even though I just moved the value `-1` into it. Any ideas?

Comment: @PeterCordes - I made an update to the question if it helps.

Comment: The debugger used to have pseudo-variables with register names but that got flakey a while ago afaik.  Use Debug > Windows > Registers to see register values.

Comment: @UndercoverCoder: In your 2nd try, you used `mov rbx, -1` instead of or as well as `mov ax, -1`?  And you were looking at the register value *after* the instruction executed, not just before?  (Still odd that it would be zero; most registers usually have some non-zero old value in them most of the time, but of course zero is more common than any other value, e.g. from loops that ended when a register reached zero.)

Comment: @PeterCordes -  Thank you sir, I realised that maybe I paused the debugger too soon thanks to your comment. So I added a print statement after the function is called in `C++`. I paused after the print statement was successful then checked the register and it had the hex value for `-1`. I guess it just took very long.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "took very long".  Set a breakpoing on `mov rbx, -1`, single-step forward by one instruction to execute it, and RBX will hold -1.  Looking *after* `printf()` returns only works because RBX is call-preserved:  your function modifies RBX (which `main` is expecting you not to, BTW).  `printf` saves/restore's `main`'s RBX if it uses it at all, because in the x86-64 Windows calling convention, it's call-preserved.  (Unlike `rcx` or `rdx`, for example, which are call-clobbered.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - I removed the print statement and set a breakpoint at `mov rbx, -1`, and it did nothing. However, it did work when I added a breakpoint on `ret` and the register `rbx` was set to `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, which is `-1` in hex if I'm not mistaken. But it's still not working for `rax`. Is this perhaps a problem with the register itself?

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on an instruction, it stops *before* that instruction runs.  **You have to single-step once to run the instruction you stopped at**.  This lets you see the state *before* as well as after.  It also lets you debug a function where the first instruction crashes.  Think of a breakpoint as entering the debugger instead of running the instruction.

Comment: Basically, if you're not seeing RAX = -1 change when you single step past `mov rax, -1`, you're using your debugger wrong.  If you see RAX with some different value many instructions later, that's because later instructions wrote RAX.

Comment: @PeterCodes - I've sorted it now, thank you very much for you patience haha, I'm newbie at anything low-level. Turns out I have to save my `C++` file too anytime I make changes in `ASSEMBLY` only. Not sure why that is, but it seems to have worked.

Comment: @UndercoverCoder, As you found the solution, if possible, you could add your solution as the answer, and then mark it. So it could help other community members who get the same issue. Thanks for your sharing. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** To solve the issue, I first added a breakpoint on each instruction. This enables us to run the program "in steps".

Then DURING THE DEBUG I went to the to top menu and selected:

`Debug >> Windows >> Registers`.

This will enable you yo see all registers.

I then saved BOTH `ASSEMBLY` and `C++` files then run it (you can use F5 as a shortcut to run).

**NOTE:** The program will perform all instructions BEFORE THE BREAKPOINT.

So if I set a breakpoint at `mov ax -1`, all instructions BEFORE ONLY will be performed.

Comment: **F11** run each instruction in step... No need to set breakpoints on every line (although setting a lot of breakpoint might sometime be useful to check which execution path are taken in a function with many branches). Usually, you set the breakpoint on the first line, then advance by using either **F10** or **F11**.